# Keyboard input problems with multiple players

Tags: c++, class, input, sdl, game-development

I'm working on the motion for my paddles in my PONG clone and the program doesn't want to register SDL_KEYUP/DOWN sometimes. I think I have an idea of why this is but now how to fix it. So the way my game is looped currently I am using a state machine in my main() function that uses a `Game` class state which manages two paddles and a ball all of which are three different class instances. In side my `Game` class I run the events/logic/render from all three classes like so

```
void Game::events()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        PlayerOne.events();
        PlayerTwo.events();
        Game_Ball.events();
    }
}

void Game::logic()
{
    PlayerOne.logic(delta.get_ticks());
    PlayerTwo.logic(delta.get_ticks());
    Game_Ball.logic();
}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0));
    PlayerOne.render();
    PlayerTwo.render();
    Game_Ball.render();
}
```

And the `paddle` class movement is managed like so (as fixed in the last question I had(:

```
void Paddle::events()
{
        Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (player == 1)
            {
                if (keystates[SDLK_o] == 1)
                {
                    yVel -= 100;
                }
                if (keystates[SDLK_k] == 1)
                {
                    yVel += 100;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (keystates[SDLK_w] == 1)
                {
                    yVel -= 100;
                }
                if (keystates[SDLK_s] == 1)
                {
                    yVel += 100;
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
        {
            if (player == 1)
            {
                if (keystates[SDLK_o] == 0)
                {
                    yVel += 100;
                }
                if (keystates[SDLK_k] == 0)
                {
                    yVel -= 100;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (keystates[SDLK_w] == 0)
                {
                    yVel += 100;
                }
                if (keystates[SDLK_s] == 0)
                {
                    yVel -= 100;
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
}
```

The problem here is that sometimes, if not most of the time, the keys don't react to move the player paddles up and down. but when they do it's less than half the time. I think this is because there is only a 1/3 chance that the program polls when a key is released or pressed, sometimes resulting in no change in the position. Basically, if PLAYERONE hits a key while `Game` is running `PlayerTwo.events()` it won't register the key press/release. Could this be a problem in the way I'm implementing the game loop in my main function?

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //init SDL
    if (init() == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //load everything
    if (load_files() == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    delta.start();
    currentState = new Game;
    while (quit == false)
    {
        //handle state events
        currentState->events();
        // do state logic
        currentState->logic();
        //timer reset
        delta.start();
        //change state if needed
        change_state();
        //render state 
        currentState->render();
        if (SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    clean_up();
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the definitions and constructors

```
class Paddle
{
public:
    int player;
    SDL_Surface *sprite = NULL;
    float x, y, w, h;
    float yVel;
    SDL_Rect *clip;
    void events();
    void logic(Uint32 deltaTicks);
    void render();
    Paddle();
    ~Paddle();
};

class Game : public GameState
{
private:
    int server;
    TTF_Font *score = NULL;
    Paddle PlayerOne;
    Paddle PlayerTwo;
    Ball Game_Ball;
public:
    SDL_Rect clip[2];
    void events();
    void logic();
    void render();
    Game();
    ~Game();
};

Game::Game()
{
    //RESOURSES
    PlayerOne.sprite = load_image("Game_sprite.png");
    PlayerTwo.sprite = load_image("Game_sprite.png");
    clip[0].x = 0;
    clip[0].y = 0;
    clip[0].w = 20;
    clip[0].h = 20;
    clip[1].x = 0;
    clip[1].y = 20;
    clip[1].w = 20;
    clip[1].h = 100;
    //PLAYER ONE
    PlayerOne.x = 420;
    PlayerOne.y = 100;
    PlayerOne.w = 60;
    PlayerOne.h = 100;
    PlayerOne.clip = &clip[1];
    PlayerOne.yVel = 0;
    PlayerOne.player = 1;
    //PLAYER TWO
    PlayerTwo.x = 60;
    PlayerTwo.y = 100;
    PlayerTwo.w = 60;
    PlayerTwo.h = 100;
    PlayerTwo.clip = &clip[1];
    PlayerTwo.yVel = 0;
    PlayerTwo.player = 2;
    //BALL
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.x = 190;
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.y = 190;
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.w = 60;
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.h = 60;
    Game_Ball.clip = &clip[0];
}
```

Because that looks pretty clean to me. Other than another game loop implementation, what could I do to fix the keys not registering due to being in a different function? Or is it a loop implementation problem? If it is a loop problem, can you be through or include a reference as to how to fix it?

Comment: Is this single threaded?  Why not try the polling loop on a separate thread.  That way, it won't be dependent on how long the rest of the processes in the game loop take.

Comment: @cup IIRC in SDL, the polling thread has to be the same as the one that has set the video mode. I think that would make some unnecessary mess.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong in this code. However, the very possible cause might be simply limitation of how many keys are pressed on keyboard. Try using *shift*, *ctrl* and *alt*, keys for controls, they usually bypass the limitation.